Beat Saber says I have the wrong OpenXR runtime using Meta Quest Link
Beat Saber says I have the wrong OpenXR runtime using Meta Quest Link.
I made the non-VR resolution 800x600 for performance. Now it doesn't work, and quite obviously, I can't go back in and change it. So now what?
